# Marge 2 response in array object React native hooks useState Array

Tags: react-native, concatenation, chat, chatbot

I am making a chat in react native. Onload first come 10 data, than comes 10 data after scrolling. I want to see old data and new data both in FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this will work for you**

```
  const [arrChatlist, setarrChatlist] = useState([]);
```

append data in existing list like this

```
setarrChatlist((arrChatlist) =>
          pageNo == 1
            ? response.data.result.data
            : [...arrChatlist, ...response.data.result.data]
        );
```